# How to print text on new line using "\n"

Tags: java

I try to create one big `String` in appropriate format as i want and print it using `PrinterJob` class. Here is the code of String:

```
String bigtext = "The name\n" + "some another text";
Graphics2D's_object.drawString(bigtext, 50, 50);
```

But it prints as `"The name some another text"` in one line, `"\n"` does not work, while i want to print `"some another text"` in another line.

P.S. I try to print bigtext in printer.

SOLVED: Here is the solution: [Problems with newline in Graphics2D.drawString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413132/problems-with-newline-in-graphics2d-drawstring). (after long trouble :))

Comment: you should consider to add the code where your displaying the info so we can help

Comment: Can you please provide some code snippets? We know how to concatenate strings, but how do you print them?

Comment: provide your current out put and expected out put in formated manner. I can't see any difference in there two.

Comment: see for me its working .Its your code  http://ideone.com/YMNIXO

Comment: Still dont get what you mean with "printer". You have a `PrinterJob`. You have s `String` to print. Then you do what?

Comment: I suggest you add the code you use in your Printable class, if you use one. Or the rest of the code for that matter, so we may help you properly.

Comment: You want to have line breaks when printing the text with PrinterJob. Add this into your question...

Answer (score 1):

The linefeed character `\n` is not the line separator in certain operating systems  use `\r\n`. Additionally i would recommend use of `StringBuilder` rather then using `+`

Edit : You can use `System.getProperty("line.separator");` as well.

Answer (score 1):

A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637341/java-what-am-i-doing-wrong-i-want-the-line/20637843#20637843) was asked yesterday and this is what helped:

The problem that you are encountering is because of the "line separator" you are hard coding. It's best to get the System's line separator with:

```
System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

So that your code would look like this:

```
   String lineseparator=System.getProperty("line.separator");
   // I'd suggest putting this as a class variable, so that it only gets called once
   // rather than everytime you call the addLine() method

  String bigtext = "The name" + lineseparator + "some another text";

 //If you wanted an empty line in between them, then add the lineseparator twice
  String bigtext = "The name" + lineseparator + lineseparator + "some another text";
```

Comment: It does not help unfortunately.

Comment: Could you post the rest of the code, so that we may help you?

Answer (score 1):

It seems most of the guys don't understand the question. I tried the PrinterJob and it doesn't work for me neither.

I found a solution but not verifyied:

[How to print strings with line breaks in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794382/how-to-print-strings-with-line-breaks-in-java)